# Save goals per client in a Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, activityhistory, goals

It is possible create some sql query (or other way) to save each journey goal reached per client in a Data Extension?

My hope was the Data Views Journey and Journey Activity but unfortunately the information is not at client level.

Best regards,
Pedro Pereira

Comment: check out this post https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/265652/query-contacts-that-exit-journey

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to save the Journey Goals per each customer but you can use the Update Contact activities to populate a Data Extension with the customers who reached the goal or right before exiting the path.

Comment: If the client reach the goal before the update contact activity it will exit the journey without populate the Data Extension.
I can create an automation that checks every goal for each client in a hourly bases and change the final Data Extension if necessary, but it is not a user friendly approach.