# What is the best way to export journey audiences?

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, journeybuilder, automationstudio, history-tracking

I would like to understand if there is a standard best practice to export the list of subscribers enter a journey whose audience is refreshed in a daily basis (and, as a plus, to combine that information with the tracking data). So far, I understand there are two main options (the 'drag-and-drop' one and the 'coding' one):

- **Automation Studio**: using SQL queries to create a kind of historical Data Extension where to add all the audiences enter in the journey. And using the Update Activity in the journey to flag if the customer opened/clicked in the email.
- **APIs**: to apply the same logic in Automation Studio but in a real-time way.

Is there any other way to do it? Please feel free to add your thoughts.

Comment: read the second answer, haven't tried this myself (as it involves a paid SF implementation), but want to. It sounds like it's the most comprehensive approach to this usecase: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/265652/query-contacts-that-exit-journey/265821#265821

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option would be to query multiple data views and place it in a DE. This helps to capture subscriber,Journey & Email specific data.

You can use automation studio to schedule this on a daily basis.

Refer this article -
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_query_journey_builder_sends_in_last_24_hours.htm&type=0

In addition to the sends you can also capture opens, clicks, bounces, complaints, or unsubscribes by modifying the data views using similar type of query, as mentioned in the article.

Alternate option would be to schedule reports and place it in FTP or send csv to your email. These reports can later be joined using queries -

1. For Journey specific tracking and engagement metrics use 'Journey Builder Email sends by day' report
2. For Subscriber specific metrics like opens,clicks etc use 'Subscriber Engagement' report